# Android : 400 Error code when accessing a RESTful webservice

Tags: android, rest, error-code

I want to access a Restful web service. I want the request should be in the following format.

```
GET /API/Contacts/username HTTP/1.1 
HOST: $baseuri:port 
Accept: text/xml 
Authorization: Basic ZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXR=
```

And also I am calling the web service though HTTPS protocol.
The folowing is the code I am using :

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://secure.myapp.com/MyApp/API/Contacts/myname");

  get.addHeader("Accept","text/xml");
  get.addHeader("Authorization","Basic ZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXR=");          
  get.addHeader("Host","https://secure.myapp.com");
  get.addHeader("Connection Use","HTTP 1.1");

  DefaultHttpClient client =  new DefaultHttpClient();
  ResponseHandler objHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
  String getResponse = client.execute(get,objHandler);
```

But I am getting an Error : 400 Bad request.

I am not sure whether my code is correct. Is it necessary to specify the method (GET, POST or PUT) explicitly in the header?

Please help me...
Thnking You....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh...
That was my mistake.
I did not keep the order of adding headers.
When I changed its order according to the Request it is working fine.

In the request the HOST should be the first parameter. 
The following is the corrected code.

```
get.addHeader("Host","secure.myapp.com");
get.addHeader("Accept","text/xml");   
get.addHeader("Authorization","Basic ZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXR=");                
get.addHeader("Connection Use","HTTP 1.1");
```

Sorry to disturb you all...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you put 'Basic ZmF0aWdhYmxlIGdlbmVyYXR=' in double quotes? 
Also check web service example request and response and make sure that everything is specified.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to put the quotes in the question. Actually i used quotes in my request. But not working